# `C-h` without knowing the type of an object

Tags: help

When someone use the Emacs inbuild help via `C-h` she/he has to know and understand if the object of interest is a function (`C-h f`), a variable (`C-h v`), a package (`C-h p`) or something else.

The differences between these types are unknown for new users.

Isn't there a magic package out there that can check this by itself and do the right thing? E.g. `C-h x` or `C-h h`.

Comment: Well, there's `C-h o`. I'm not sure if it qualifies as magic, but it's useful!

Comment: @aadcg: Please consider adding that as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Drew mentions, the `apropos` commands are extremely important. The word derives from the French "à-propos" which can be translated as "in connection", "with regard" or "concerning".  In other words, *apropos foo* means *concerning foo*.

In practice, I frequently use `describe-symbol`, bound to `C-h o` by default, since it describes variables, functions and faces.

Emacs' help system is advanced and it may take some time to wrap one's head around it. When in doubt, run `C-h C-h` for a description of all help commands.

Answer (score 5):

1. The apropos commands are your friend. Command `apropos` is the most general:

> **`apropos`** is an autoloaded interactive Lisp function in `apropos.el`.
>
> It is bound to `<menu-bar> <help-menu> <search-documentation> <find-any-object-by-name>`.
>
> `(apropos PATTERN &optional DO-ALL)`
>
> Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 1.8.
>
> Show all meaningful Lisp symbols whose names match `PATTERN`.
>
> Symbols are shown if they are defined as functions, variables, or
> faces, or if they have nonempty property lists.
>
> `PATTERN` can be a word, a list of words (separated by spaces),
> or a regexp (using some regexp special characters).  If it is a word,
> search for matches for that word as a substring.  If it is a list of words,
> search for matches for any two (or more) of those words.
>
> With `C-u` prefix, or if **`apropos-do-all`** is non-`nil`,
> consider all symbols (if they match `PATTERN`).
>
> Returns list of symbols and documentation found.

2. **`C-h S`** looks up a symbol in the manuals:

> **`C-h S`** runs the command **`info-lookup-symbol`** (found in `global-map`), which
> is an autoloaded interactive Lisp function in `info-look.el`.
>
> It is bound to `C-h S`, `<f1> S`, `<help> S`.
>
> `(info-lookup-symbol SYMBOL &optional MODE)`
>
> Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 20.1.
>
> Display the definition of `SYMBOL`, as found in the relevant manual.
>
> When this command is called interactively, it reads `SYMBOL` from the
> minibuffer.  In the minibuffer, use `M-n` to yank the default argument
> value into the minibuffer so you can edit it.  The default symbol is the
> one found at point.
>
> With prefix arg `MODE` a query for the symbol help mode is offered.

Comment: What is a "symbol"?

Comment: @buhtz: In this case, more or less a name that matches the regexp `[a-z]+\\s +\\([_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*\\)`

Answer (score 2):

Package [helpful](https://github.com/wilfred/helpful) provides `helpful-callable`, for which you don't need to know whether the thing you're inquiring about is a command, function, or macro because it checks them all, and also `helpful-symbol`, which like `describe-symbol` [mentioned previously](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/69342/18389) will

> Show help for `SYMBOL`, a variable, function or macro.

…by evaluating `SYMBOL` and calling `helpful-callable` or `helpful-variable` as appropriate (and asking which you want if it could be either—though unlike with `describe-symbol` you have to pick one, you don't get both).